# Yii CJuiDatePicker is not working when page loaded with ajax but works with direct url access

Tags: php, yii, widget

It is little confusing the working of CJuiDatePicker widget. when i accessing page with direct  URL it working fine and calender displayed as required but the problem is that when i load the page into a dynamic portion with ajax call,Only text-fields are appearing but calender is not displaying after clicking on it.

```
$this->renderPartial('index', array('policyModel' => $policyModel, 'roomModel' => $roomModel, 'formModel' => $formModel,'response' => $response),false,true);
```

Widget Code

```
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
   'name' => 'start_date',
    'options' => array(
        'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
        'showAnim' => 'fadeIn', 
        'changeMonth' => true,
        'changeYear' => true,
        'yearRange' => '2000:2099',
        'minDate' => '+1d',
        'maxDate' => '10Y',
    ),
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'readonly' => 'readonly',
        'size' => 7,
    ),
));
```

Can any one please help me ,I am posting the question after so many hours of search.

Comment: The code you mentioned works fine in ajax call, There is some thing other issue, please add more code, this will help to find the exact issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set a unique ID for the datepicker. I do so with the php-function **uniqid()**

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
   'id' => 'start_date'.uniqid(),
   'name' => 'start_date',
    'options' => array(
        'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
        'showAnim' => 'fadeIn', 
        'changeMonth' => true,
        'changeYear' => true,
        'yearRange' => '2000:2099',
        'minDate' => '+1d',
        'maxDate' => '10Y',
    ),
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'readonly' => 'readonly',
        'size' => 7,
    ),
));
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need re-init datepicker after ajax update.After Ajax done, you'll need to add the following line:

```
$('#start_date').datepicker(); //with your options
```

Comment: I do not advise you to use Jui widgets with ajax. Much safer to write in jquery.